# How can I use two selectors in a jQuery function, to do the same actions?

Tags: jquery

I want to do the same action for two selectors. I need something like this:

```
$("#ddlSuperFuncao or #ddlMeta").on('change', function () {
     alert('Same action when I change one div or other');
}
```

Have any way to do this or I need to use selector as a variavel and pass it when I detect which elements have been changed?

Comment: use a common class for both elements

Comment: FYI "'Same action when I change one **div** or other'" DIV doesn't have any change event but can be still fired if DIV contains any input element

Comment: A.Wolff thank you, I'm wrong when I write this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `,` to pass [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#ddlSuperFuncao , #ddlMeta").on('change', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as following:

```
  $("#ddlSuperFuncao, #ddlMeta").on('change', function () {
         alert('Same action when I change one div or other');
  }
```

For more information read it from [here](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).